# Measure object in a photo, without a smartphone

Tags: photos

I see a number of apps for [measuring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vistechprojects.partometer) [size](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=si.sis.mymeasures) [of objects](http://compixels.com/276/measure-objects-in-photo-using-photoruler-for-iphone) [in photos](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easymeasure-measure-your-camera!/id349530105) -- if one has a smart phone. I don't. Are there any online services which can do same? Or program for Windows PC?

No 100mb trial ware or demo's please as I only need it for one job, namely getting the surface dimensions of a table:

[image: pic of table]

Comment: What have you tried so far? I assume you've at least looked but didn't like what you found or are you saying you can't find anything? My first search brought up a [YouTube video doing this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cX3eUwHunZM)

Comment: @Dave I've searched and found 2 or 3 programs for converting photos to 3d models, and have a measuring component, but they're expensive and/or require 100mb+ download and install of trialware. I've come across a few forum threads which discuss how one might measure size of known object in pixels, apply a math ratio against it's real world size, apply some other formulas to correct for perspective and lens distortion and so on, but they're beyond me. I didn't discover that Youtube video, I'll take a look (but later, on the computer I'm using now flash keeps crashing when I try).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KLONK Image Measurement](http://www.imagemeasurement.com) for this task.

You first take a picture of table in a perpendicular angle on what you want to measure. On the image you must place an object which you know the size of.

And then you aquire it into the application, calibrate according to the object and the measure what you need to measure.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer but not voting up. Why: a) the install program provokes an automatic reboot without warning or chance to abort or save open documents in other programs; b) before program will run it requires registration (email, name, company, etc., etc); c) images must be calibrated before they can be measured (which makes sense, but instructions for doing so are limited, and there's no library of known objects and size from which to choose for calibration).

Comment: This program is awful!  It looks sophisticated with lots of icons and buttons but doesn't do much better than the most basic of its competitors.  It is unbelievably buggy!  Buttons are mysteriously  deactivated.  The pricing is so high that it is laughable.  I would expect an image program to at least account for skewed images.

You're better off using one of those free mobile apps that do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem and found this:
http://dew.globalsystemsscience.org/software

With the related tutorial here:
http://k12s.phast.umass.edu/sess/Pickle/guides/MakingMeasurementDigitalImagesV3.pdf

Comment: Don't post links as answers; If they answer the question, post the link AND a summary of the documents.